# Is there any need to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState when using Android Architecture Components LiveData & ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

[Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) provide the `LiveData` and `ViewModel` classes which are more lifecycle-friendly and designed for a leaner Activity/Fragment. These classes handle storing data across configuration changes, but I'm confused about their use compared to the Activity framework APIs. Are  `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` still necessary or useful for preserving activity state?

Answer (score 3):

onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState is still useful.

ViewModel holds data only when process is alive.
But, onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState can hold data even if process is killed.

ViewModel is easy to use and useful for preserving large data when screen orientation changes.
onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState can preserve data when process is in background.(in background, app process can be killed by system at anytime.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume a scenario : 
user is in `activity A` , then navigates to `activity B`

but because of low memory Android OS destroys `activity A` , therefor the `ViewModel` connected to it also destroys. (You can emulate it by checking `Don't keep activities` in Developer options)

now user navigates back to `activity A`, Android OS try's to create new `Acivity` and `ViewModel` objects. therefor you loosed data in `ViewModel`.

But still values in savedInstanceState are there.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other answers which talk about the `ViewModel`'s persistence beyond simply configuration changes, I think there are a couple more use cases:

## Performance reasons

Sometimes you don't want to store **all** of the latest values of view attributes in the `ViewModel` for performance reasons. You may have greater need to save them when the view is being re-created. For example, user's scroll position on a view within your activity/fragment. You probably don't want to save the scroll position every time the user scrolls. But you might want to save that `onSaveInstanceState` so you can restore that when the view is recreated (`onRestoreInstanceState`).

## Initialization to perform after restore

Some views may require initialization especially because of the restore, due to the complex design of those views not being able to save everything. For example, I had a `WebView` and if the user was in the middle of loading a page during a configuration change, I want the `WebView` to try to load the new page (rather than the old one). After restoring the state, the observers of `LiveData` will get the latest values but this doesn't help much with something like this (I only want the view to load a page from the ViewModel at the point of restore, not at other times). So we just do that initialization via the restore state.

## Final word

With all this stuff I would advocate keeping your `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` as simple as possible. Ideally just call a method on the ViewModel and that's it. Then we can extract all of the logic from the view into the ViewModel, and the view is just left with boilerplate code.