# Do we still need onSaveInstanceState() when we have ViewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

Now with the View model as we can handle the configuration changes and manage the UI data, So the onSaveInstance() I feel now if of no use for me.

Like earlier we used to store smaller data onSaveInstanceState() and used to restore it during configuration, now using view model we can easily get the updated data. So could you please tell me whats the actual usage of **onSaveInstanceState()** and **onRestoreInstancestate()** now if we are using ViewModel.

Could you please tell me the usage of it in the current case with ViewModel

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561364/is-there-any-need-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-when-usi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any need to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState when using Android Architecture Components LiveData & ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561364/is-there-any-need-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-when-usi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data can still be lost when Android OS decides to kill your application process due to memory constraints and then later re-create it. This is different from Configuration changes.

`ViewModel` successfully saves your data from the configuration change (`Activity`/`Fragment` Recreation), but it won't be of much help in case of [Process Recreation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLCn27DceRA).

In order to persist data even in case of Process Recreation, you will need to use `onSaveInstanceState()`.

However with recent updates, by means of [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) `ViewModel` directly allows you to save instance state, which will automatically survive process death/recreation. This implies, you no more need to use `onSaveInstanceState` of your `Activity/Fragment` to persist data across process death, just use `SavedStateHandle` in your `ViewModel`, it will act the same.